# Bean is not formed for datasource in Spring MVC Project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am facing error "Property datasource is required".

Below is the configuration in dao-beans xml.

```
<bean id="Template" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/TEMPLATES" />
    </bean>

<bean id="languageDao" class="com.test.daoImpl.LanguageDAOImpl"
        init-method="init">
        <property name="cspLanguageGet" value="csp_LANGUAGE_Get" />
    </bean>
```

Class has the following configurations:

```
private DataSource Template;

    private SimpleJdbcCall languageGet;

    private String cspLanguageGet;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Template")
    public void setTemplate(DataSource Template) {
        this.Template = Template;
    }

    @Required
    public void setCspLanguageGet(String cspLanguageGet) {
        this.cspLanguageGet = cspLanguageGet;
    }

    public void init() {
        this.languageGet = new SimpleJdbcCall(Template).withProcedureName(cspLanguageGet);
        this.languageGet.compile();
    }
```

I tried with the many solutions which I found over but no luck.I can't use  since my java version is 1.8

Below is the error stack trace.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:134)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:165)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.<init>(AbstractJdbcCall.java:87)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.<init>(SimpleJdbcCall.java:69)
        at com.aexp.travel.docdelivery.tcapp.daoImpl.LanguageDAOImpl.init(LanguageDAOImpl.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Context.xml deployed in tomcat has the following configuration:

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/TEMPLATES"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="30"
    maxWait="10000"
    driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://gtwtdwdbsqlv001.gbt.gbtad.com:1433;databaseName=Template"
    username="Test"
    password="*******"
    />
```

I am stuck in this from past 3 days.Not able to resolve this.Can anyone pls help me to understand where it is going wrong

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575383/why-use-jndiobjectfactorybean-to-config-jndi-datasource-did-not-work

Comment: @clevertension,but all of these bean configuration are in my xml file,so how will I call  afterPropertiesSet() on jndiObjectFactoryBean

Comment: @clevertension,Can you pls suggest

Comment: try to configure resource from "jdbc/TEMPLATES" to "/jdbc/TEMPLATES"

Comment: Please don't ask [the same question twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60201716/invocation-of-init-method-failed-nested-exception-is-java-lang-illegalargumente)! Instead update your original one with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which version of Spring you are using but **You may include DataSoure bean** as shown below

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:file:C:/temp/test" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
</bean>
```

**OR**

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
  DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
  dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
  dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:file:C:/temp/test");
  dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
  dataSourceBuilder.password("");
  return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: No you don't. You can do a JNDI lookup perfectly fine.

Comment: @M.Deinum Is answer irrelevant or you just provided additional way. On what basis it has been downgraded please elaborate

Comment: Because you can do a JNDI lookup as well. There is no MUST way to define a datasource. If you have a datasource managed by your app server, you do a JNDI lookup you don't re-define the datasource again.

Comment: Language can be edited but downgrading isn't a solution. This kind of behaviour isn't acceptable

Comment: Nor will this solve the error by the user, so it isn't an answer to the question as well. As that is a matter of wrongly configured XML not of a wrongly configured datasource (or datasource lookup as the topic starter already has).

Comment: The error user has received is clearly mentioning "Datasource" bean isn't available. There are multiple ways to solve that. And defining bean of ds is one of them. I don't think answer has some improper information

Comment: Which comes from the `init` method. If the JNDI lookup would fail, the error would be a different one. So the answer won't help in solving the error in the init. Which is due to wrongly or missing configuration. Propably annotation processing because he is mixing XML and annotation config.